# how to copy directory from one partition to another?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, copy

I'm going to try to keep this short. I damaged my install of ubuntu server, so I resided the partition and installed it again. Before I did that I made a backup of everything I wanted to keep inside my /home dir. How can I get that back onto my new installation?

Comment: you can put the content of /home backup into a different partition, and on the install process, mount that partition on /home. If you already did  the install, you can follow this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving, in order to point /home to that partition. You should take care that UID and GUID of your new installation match the values on the /home backup. I do not know if chown recursevely will work if those do not match.

Comment: In a hundred different ways, you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way (if yoou do not want to use pure terminal commands) is to install midnight commander, a textbased file-manager.

```
sudo apt-get install mc

sudo mc
```

Be aware that eventually you might have to change permissions and ownership of files.